# window.onload != <body onload="">

Tags: javascript, collections, onload

This is rather interesting, I think. Consider following code, both the window.onload and body onload="" call the same function. However, the results are different. It appears to me that window.onload has a problem with collections. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = getSpanElements();

    function getSpanElements(){
        var collectionBoolean = document.getElementsByTagName("span")?true:false;
        alert(
            "collection exists? " + collectionBoolean + "; number of collection members: " + document.getElementsByTagName("span").length
        );
    }


</script>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="getSpanElements()">
    <span> test </span>
</body>
```

As you can see, both report that the collection exists, however window.onload reports that it has no members. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're setting the function wrong:

```
window.onload = getSpanElements();
```

should be

```
window.onload = getSpanElements;
```

You're setting the onload handler to the return value of getSpanElements() at the moment.

Answer (score 10):

```
window.onload = getSpanElements();
```

should be

```
window.onload = getSpanElements;
```

The code you have **calls** the `getSpanElements` function and assigns its **return value** as the onload event handler.

Answer (score 3):

You're wrongly doing this:

```
window.onload = getSpanElements();
```

which sets the `window.onload` to the result of the call to the function `getSpanElements` (undefined).

You should do this instead:

```
window.onload = getSpanElements;
```

Comment: actually, the function returns `undefined`, not `null`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to move your window.onload assignment below the getSpanElements declaration:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">


        function getSpanElements(){
                var collectionBoolean = document.getElementsByTagName("span")?true:false;
                alert(
                        "collection exists? " + collectionBoolean + "; number of collection members: " + document.getElementsByTagName("span").length
                );
        }

        window.onload = getSpanElements;

</script>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="getSpanElements()">
        <span> test </span>
</body>
```

At the point in your code where you're assigning the window.onload event handler, getSpanElements() has not yet been defined. Also, the line should be

```
window.onload=getSpanElements;
```

not

```
window.onload=getSpanElements();
```

The function name without parentheses is a reference to the function. With parentheses, it executes the function and the return value is assigned to window.onload.

Comment: Since getSpanElements is defined with the function statement rather than the function expression, it is subject to hoisting — so it doesn't need appear before the assignment in the code order.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign a reference to the function `getSpanElements` to `window.onload` - currently, the function doesn't get executed `onload`, but immediately after parsing.

What you actually assign is the undefined return value.

In short: drop the `()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `window` object is created before any actual elements are parsed.

Comment: i would assume so as well, however it is well aware that the collection exists, that is what confuses me.